# access user control method in aspx page

Tags: c#, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap-3, user-controls

I have user control with modal popup which is used to show popup whenever necessary.

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel"
    aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
         <asp:UpdatePanel ID="upModal" runat="server" ChildrenAsTriggers="false" UpdateMode="Conditional">
            <ContentTemplate>
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">
                    &times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">
                    <asp:Label ID="lblModalTitle" runat="server"></asp:Label></h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <asp:Label ID="lblModalBody" runat="server"></asp:Label>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button class="btn btn-info" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">
                    Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
    </div>
</div>
```

**And back end**

```
private string _Title = null;

public string Title
        {
        get
            {
            return _Title;
            }
        set
            {
            _Title = value;
            }
        }

private string _message = null;

public string Message
        {
        get
            {
            return _message;
            }
        set
            {
            _message = value;
            }
        }
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        if (_Title != null)
            {
            lblModalTitle.Text = _Title;
            lblModalBody.Text = _message;
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType(), "myModal", "$('#myModal').modal({backdrop: 'static',keyboard: false});", true);
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType(), "myModal", "$('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () { $('#lblModalTitle').focus();})", true);
            upModal.Update();
            }
        }
```

Now I have aspx page. after the user clicks, server click event generates and after the operation ends I want to show popup with this user control.

what should I have to do that ? currently I implemented interface with method and **overridden** that method and accessed that in **aspx** page.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a script block to the  section or the head content place holder to open your modal and anything else you want to do there.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function openMyModal() {
        $('#myModal').modal('show');
    }
</script>
```

Then you can just call the function from the codebehind

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "Popup", "openMyModal();", true);
```